# Nested AngularJS directives... What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So, I've been banging my head against my keyboard for the past few hours trying to figure out how to turn this:

```
<scope-filter label="Sort by" type="sort">  
    <scope-filter-item key="recent">Recent Activity</scope-filter-item>  
    <scope-filter-item key="influence">Influence</scope-filter-item>
    <scope-filter-item key="loyalty">Loyalty</scope-filter-item>
    <scope-filter-item key="followers">Followers</scope-filter-item>
    <scope-filter-item key="visits">Visits</scope-filter-item>
</scope-filter>
```

Into this:

```
<div>
  <label>Sort By:</label>
  <ul>
    <li>Recent Activity</li>
    <li>Influence</li>
    <li>Loyalty</li>
    <li>Followers</li>
    <li>Visits</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using this: http://jsfiddle.net/qBnDF/14/

For some odd reason, `scope-filter-item` entries are only being processed and associated with `scope-filter` if I include `<div ng-transclude></div>` within the `scope-filter.html` template.

There are quite a few more things this directive is going to do, but to keep things simple, I'll just extract all the unnecessary stuff unrelated to the actual problem.

From what I've read about directives is that you should be able to pass a controller from the parent to the child by using the `require: '^thingToRequire'` syntax. This then should inject the parent controller into the child controllers `link` method.

Not really sure what's going on here. Sorry, I'm more of an angular novice at the moment and this is kind of voodoo / black magic to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you are trying to filter a list and want the ability to switch the type of filters? If so, `ng-switch` will work fine for you: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you want:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="scope-filter.html">
  <div>
    <label>{{ label }}:</label>            
      <ul ng-transclude></ul>           
  </div>
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
sandbox.directive('scopeFilterItem', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^scopeFilter',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<li ng-transclude></li>',
    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, scopeFilter) {
        scopeFilter.addScopeFilterItem(iAttrs.key)
    }
  }
});
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qBnDF/17/).

I removed the `value` argument from `addScopeFilterItem` because it isn't needed in this example. If you need it back for some reason, I suggest that you add a new attribute to `scopeFilterItem` - `value`, perhaps - and get it from there.

Finally, you need to use transclusion so Angular doesn't discard the contents of the `<scope-filter>` tag. Check out this little [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQVp6/) script and notice that the directive's content only gets rendered if transclusion is enabled.

Comment: Gah! So close! That did the trick, buddy! Still trying to navigate these waters,but you certainly helped! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

> scope-filter-item entries are only being processed and associated with
>   scope-filter if I include  within the
>   scope-filter.html template

`scope-filter-item`'s won't call linking function without being present anywhere in DOM. What `ng-transclude` did was to compile whole `scope-filter` and insert it into DOM, which made the code work.

Depending on what you want to achieve, there are several options:

1. Follow Michael Benford's advice.
2. Provide data some other way instead of `scope-filter-item` tags. For example, expose  items object through `ng-model` directive. This would be easier, but I don't know reasons behind your decision, so this might not suit.
3. Drop `scopeFilterItem` directive and get items via manual transclusion in `scopeFilter`.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qBnDF/19/).

**JavaScript**

```
sandbox.directive('scopeFilter', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'scope-filter.html',
        scope: {
            label: '@label',
            type: '@type'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $transclude) {
            $scope.items = [];
            $transclude(function (clone) {
                angular.forEach(clone, function(item) {
                    if (item.tagName !== "SCOPE-FILTER-ITEM") return;
                    $scope.items.push({
                        key: item.getAttribute("key"),
                        value: item.innerText
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="scope-filter.html">
    <div>
        <label>{{ label }}:</label>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.key }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

[This article](http://blog.omkarpatil.com/2012/11/transclude-in-angularjs.html) provides several transclusion examples, you might find it useful.